# phpMyAdmin Says 2.2GB, but the mysqldump is 25GB, any ideas why?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I am trying to figure out why my database dump is so large.

phpMyAdmin states that the total database size is 2.2GB

The MySql DUMP is 25GB

Why is the dump so much larger than the stated size in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL dumps are plain text files with the required SQL commands to recreate the tables and their contents.

Instead of this, phpMyAdmin shows the binary size of the database.

Comment: It just seems like such a huge difference, are these results typical?

Comment: It highly depends in the nature of the information you are storing, but it's not strange to get these results.

Comment: In my case, the database dump (using mysqldump) is much smaller than the database, the database is 560MB and the dump is only 281MB, any idea on why this is so ?

Comment: It does not makes sense for me... Are you sure you are checking ok the size of the database?